# COUNTIF filtered data, Criteria >0

Tags: excel-formula

How can I countif filtered data, criteria >0. I have been using this formula and it returns me 0. Does the formula need to be tweeked a little? Or could any of you please provide me a different solution.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(BV9:BV784>0,SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(BV9:BV784,ROW(BV9:BV784)-MIN(ROW(BV9:BV784)),,1)))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to improve your question with sufficient information to describe and reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SUMPRODUCT` does not work with booleans.

The only problem I could see in your formula is that

> BV9:BV784 > 0

generates a Boolean array, while you want a *numeric* zero-or-one array. You can force the conversion of the boolean array into a zero-or-one array using (among other possible ways) the `--` trick:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(BV9:BV784>0),SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(BV9:BV784,ROW(BV9:BV784)-MIN(ROW(BV9:BV784)),,1)))
'          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```